# C# reference of 2nd dim array to 1d array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a function that can take a 1d array (`double[]`) as an argument while my source data is a 2d array (`double[,]`) of 'cnt' number of 3d points, like so

```
double[,] points = new double[3,cnt]
```

But what I actually want to do is to pass on each of the three 2nd dim arrays to the function `gpu.Average(double[] arg)`, preferably without having to copy the content of the arrays value[i] by value[i]. Is that possible in C#?

**EXAMPLE CODE**

This works:

```
double[] points1d = new double[cnt];
// ... fill points1d with data, then
double a = gpu.Average(points1d);  // <- Alea.gpu.Average() accepts a 1d array
```

But as said, I want to pass on the second dimension to the function gpu.Average() whithout having to run for-loops three times to copy into 1d arrays:

```
double[,] points2d = new double[3,cnt];
// ... fill points2d with 'cnt' items of data and
// then pass it on

double x = gpu.Average(points2d[0,??]);  // How to pass on 2nd dim?
double y = gpu.Average(points2d[1,??]);     
double z = gpu.Average(points2d[2,??]);
```

Is this possible without having to copy the data into 1d arrays?

(BTW, calculating average is not a good example use of gpu parallel library, this is just a test case comparing execution times for different data types & structures).

// Rolf

Comment: No, but if you use nested arrays (`[][]`) instead of 2d arrays (`[,]`), then you can.

Comment: Hm. but can nested arrays be allocated with dynamic length? 
I'm thinking of `double[3][someList.Count]`;

Comment: If you are extremely lucky then your method will have an overload that takes a double* instead of an array.  Then you can do this.

Comment: They can be allocated however you like, but it's more code than a 2D array. You have to create each array explicitly, so you'd need a for-loop.

Comment: You can pin the array and overwrite its object header so that it looks like a one-d array of the appropriate length (for the first array).  For the later arrays you can do temporary overwrites of the last elements of the prior array and then use some CIL code to reinterpret cast the method table pointer you wrote to a managed reference of 1D array type.

Comment: You could do this with pointers ...assuming the `gpu.Average(...)` takes pointers.

Comment: How much data are in these sets?

Comment: @MatthewWhited, in my particular test case it's 47.830 Point3d. It can be up to 300.000 or more (mesh vertices).
I'm new to .NET (I'n an old ^Delphi guy...) so the question about pointers is difficult for me to answer. But this page may have the answer (I'm studiying it myself): 
http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_3/doc/gpu_programming_csharp.html#parallel_agg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible in managed code without copying the contents of e.g. `points2d[1,*]` to a new single dimensional array.

In managed code every array has to know its length, so that every index access can be checked and `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception thrown if the index is out of bounds. The length (integer value) is stored before the first element of the array, so that the runtime knows where to find it. Now with this I guess one can see why you cannot split array into several parts and treat those as new arrays. Note that the story is even more complicated for multidimensional arrays, which have to store the number of dimensions and the size of each dimension...

What you can do is to use jagged array:

```
double[][] points2d = new double[3][];
points2[0] = new double[cnt];
...
gpu.Average(points2d[0]);
```

Jagged arrays are faster than multidimensional arrays and are recommended to be used instead of multidimensional arrays [even by MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182277.aspx).

Comment: +1, though it actually is possible to do this with managed code, but the code required to do so is brutal and will crash horribly if a GC happens while the shenanigans are being performed.  Of course, you can prevent GC during, but it's not for the faint of heart.

Comment: Can you link to a MS reference saying jagged arrays are recommended over multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Unfortunately that code doesn't compile. Edit: I will test with `double[][] points2d = new double[3][];` though. bb

Comment: OK, repeatingly creating the additional three arrays [3][...] works. Which is essentially the same as creating three discrete arrays. In this case all these allocations takes 10 longer than it takes for the CPU to do the job directly, but this trick may prove to be useful in other cases. It works, and so I will accept this as The answer. Thanks a lot! 
Edit: You could add the last missing square brackets to the code example `new double[3][];` though. :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard, added reference

Comment: @hoodaticus I believe this would require unsafe code, which I would not call managed anymore.

Comment: That reference seems to be talking about only the case where a jagged array would save space; "Suppress a warning from this rule if the multidimensional array does not waste space." - which fits OP's code in this case. Interesting that they have this warning at all though, for such a specific and (I would have thought) unusual case.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, sorry I just skimmed the text of the reference. Anyway, I'm sure you can google this or just benchmark it. FAIK accessed to multidim arrays are compiled to method calls, which is just crazy slow compared to compilation of accesses to jagged arrays directly to native code equivalent.